# Unity 2d character movement inside of a coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

My character moves whatever spot you click on screen, and I put this inside of a coroutine because I'm going to have the character perform an action once they've arrived. My issue so far is for whatever reason, the first time the coroutine is called the character movement is VERY slow compared to every following time you click to move. It's not a time.deltaTime issue as the exact same thing happens without multiplying my speed by that. I'm new to coroutines so maybe I've structured this wrong? I can't wrap my head around what could cause this, and I would greatly appreciate any help!

```
 private void ClickObject()
{
    Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray);
    print("start coroutine");
    StopAllCoroutines();
    StartCoroutine(Move(hit.transform.position));
}
private IEnumerator Move(Vector3 targetPos)
{
    Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray);
    bool arrived = false;
    
        
        while (arrived == false)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            anim.Play("Walk");
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPos) == 0)
            {
                print("coroutine phase 1");
                arrived = true;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
        if (arrived == true)
        {
            anim.Play("Idle");
            print("reached position");
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                print(hit.collider.tag);
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Collect>() != null)
                {
                    Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                    print("destroy");
                }
            }
            //StopCoroutine("Move");
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you moving your player in a `Coroutine` instead of Update?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my solution is right for you, but from my previous experience, the reason why my coroutine did not work because StartCoroutine requires something that leads to the location of the actual coroutine or block of code. Sorry if the explanation isn't very clear.

So what I did:

private IEnumerator coroutine;

coroutine = method()

StartCoroutine(coroutine);

private IEnumerator method()

{

`enter code here`

}

Hope it helps you.